# Using ADO.Net DataSet can occur Data Inconsistency?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm C# beginner-level learner. When I learn about ADO.net, there are generally two main facets - connected(**DataReader**) and disconnected(**DataSet**).

According to my understanding, **DataSet** (ADO.Net Disconnected Facet) get a copy of the data from the database into memory using **DataAdapter**, automatically close the connection once it's finished the job of copying. Then the user (client) can make insert, update, delete, and select to this in-memory virtual database (**DataSet**).

Let's consider one scenario. While the user select the data and make some updates to his **in-memory database**, another user (client) commit changes to the actual database. So the first user (client) data inside of his in-memory **DataSet** will become **outdated** and **invalid**.

So I really ambiguous about whether using **ADO.Net DataSet** can occur **data inconsistencies**. Is it true? If true, how we can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, can ocurr data inconsistencies.

You need to check this article about [Optimistic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz(v=vs.110).aspx) concurrency in order to learn how to avoid this kind of problems when retrieve and store data on database with Non-Connected approach.